# FFMpeg video transpose

Tags: ffmpeg

I have movie which is rotated by 90, 180 or 270 degrees. I process that video and make and save processed copy in some place. My problem is that in my processed move rotation is not included e.g. my input video is ratated by 180 degrees but my output video is not rotated at all. Here is my commad:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vf crop=480:480:80:0 -strict -2 testMovie.mp4
```

How can I apply rotation from my input movie to my output movie.

Comment: You don't actually specify transpose in that command.

Comment: Do I need to set transpose if my input file is already transposed?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to, but we can't actually help without seeing at commands you run.

Comment: This command what I enclose in my post is not sufficient? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Running these two will produce the file `out2.mp4` which is rotated 90 degrees, and cropped afterwards. Do you get a different result?

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" out1.mp4

ffmpeg -i out1.mp4 -vf "crop=480:480:80:0" out2.mp4
```